# RxSwift state changes trigger "Warning: Recursive call or synchronization error!"

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I've inherited some Swift 3 code which uses RxSwift to manage a store. The basic layout of the class is:

```
class UserActivityStore {
    fileprivate lazy var internalDataCache: Variable<Set<NSUserActivity>?> = Variable(nil)

    func addAction(_ actionToAdd: NSUserActivity) {
        var content = internalDataCache.value ?? Set<NSUserActivity>()
        content.insert(actionToAdd)
        internalDataCache.value = content
    }

    func resolveAction(_ action: NSUserActivity) {
        var content = internalDataCache.value
        _ = content?.remove(action)
        internalDataCache.value = content
    }

    func expectActions(_ filter: @escaping ((NSUserActivity) -> Bool)) -> Observable<NSUserActivity> {
        let observable = Observable<NSUserActivity>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
            return self.internalDataCache.asObservable().subscribeNext { (newActions) in
                guard let newActions = newActions else { return }
                for eachAction in newActions where filter(eachAction) {
                    observer.onNext(eachAction)
                    self.resolveAction(eachAction)
                }
            }
        }
        return observable
    }
}
```

When an action is added to this, it adds the item to the set correctly. However, the observer (in `expectActions`) catches that change and resolves it. Since this is all in a single thread, the error "Warning: Recursive call or synchronization error!" is triggered.

I think this is a perfectly legitimate error and that RxSwift is probably correct in its handling. However, I can't help thinking that this is a bad model. The code is essentially handling a queue of `NSUserActivity` objects itself.

Is this genuinely a modelling error / abuse of RxSwift or is my limited understanding of RxSwift misunderstanding this? As a hacky solution, I've tried replacing the `resolveAction` function with a single line `internalDataCache.value?.remove(action)` but that still triggers the observable and hence the bug.

Changing the observable to use a different queue (Serial or Concurrent dispatch) fixes the problem but I'm not convinced its the correct fix.

Comment: Yea, it's a sketchy design. It looks like the intent is that whenever an activity is added or removes, the expectActions Observable sends out a stream of all current activities that match the filter. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that about sums it up.